# Viewmodel seems to be scoped to a fragment instead of activity. I am using navigation component as well

Tags: kotlin, android-viewmodel, android-architecture-navigation

I am using navigation component and I have one activity in the app with so many fragments. I am trying to use one view model scoped to the activity in all the fragments but it working only in the 3 fragments nested in my home fragment. The home fragment which is the navigation host fragment is using a view pager to add 3 tabs which are 3 fragments within the home fragment. For instance I have like 3 tabs A, B, C. Between these three I can share data in view model successfully. 'A' has a detail fragment lets call it D. when I try to access shared viewModel in D it has null values which I know I have set already in A. I have a normal view model class.
in each fragment I instantiate view model like this

`private val viewModel: MainActivityViewModel by activityViewModels()`

it seems the viewModel is only scoped to the home fragment because it not working inside any detail fragment that I navigate to. Thank you. !

just in case there is something unusual about my view model class here is how it looks like

```
class MainActivityViewModel: ViewModel() {
   var itemListLiveData = MutableLiveData<List<Item>>()

   fun setItems(itemList: List<Item>)  {
       itemListLiveData.value = itemList
   }
   fun getItems() = itemListLiveData.value
}
```

Comment: I don’t see an error in what you’ve shown so far, but it is unusual to use the LiveData value getter and I’ve seen numerous problems people have had on here arose from using it without really understanding how it works.

Answer (score 0):

You have to initialise your viewModel in onCreate method of your fragment.

```
// declare your viewModel like this
lateinit var viewModel : MainActivityViewModel

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    // other code

    // initialise your view model here
    viewModel = ViewModelProvider(requireActivity()).get(MainActivityViewModel::class.java)

    // other code

}
```

Also there is one mistake in your MainActivityViewModel class:

```
fun setItems(itemList: List<Item>)  {
   // set your live data like this
   itemListLiveData.postValue(itemList)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try instantiating your viewmodel like this

```
lateinit var viewModel: MainActivityViewModel
```

and in onViewCreated

```
viewModel = (activity as MainActivity).viewModel
```

This worked for me in the past when sharing a ViewModel.

Answer (score 0):

Oops ! sorry I found the problem which has nothing to do with the activity view model not working. but I just leave my answer in case by chance some one else has the same issue.

The problem was here

```
fun setItems(itemList: List<Item>)  {
   itemListLiveData.value = itemList
}
```

in the fragment where I set this itemList, I clear this itemList in the fragments onStop() method so because itemListLiveData.value is referencing this itemList object it is also cleared. So I resolved it by instantiating it with a new object of itemList instead of referencing the itemList object. like below

```
fun setItems(itemList: List<Item>)  {
   itemListLiveData.value = ArrayList<Item>(itemList)
}
```